# I try to sent emails from different domain names using one email account and get dmarc=fail

Tags: email, gmail, google-workspace, dmarc, google-gsuite

For example, I have:

example.com (in this domain I create account)
need.com (additional domain)
I want to give the users the ability to send emails as @need.com using alias in accounts settings.

The problem is that all messages go to spam with DMARC policies.

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; 
dkim=pass header.i=@need-com.20150623.gappssmtp.com header.s=20150623 header.b="y0qDXN/D";
spf=pass (google.com: domain of mailtest@example.com designates 209.85.220.41 as permitted sender) 
smtp.mailfrom=mailtest@example.com;
dmarc=fail (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=QUARANTINE) header.from=need.com
```

It is necessary to configure so that everything would work correctly with the quarantine DMARC policy. Is it possible? Maybe someone has a practical solution to this problem?

Presumably the problem is in the difference of headers but could not figure out how to solve it.